# Apache CSP Not Taking Effect

Tags: php, apache, content-security-policy

On my Apache `httpd.conf` file I have added the following code inside of the `<VirtualHost *:80>` section (and also uncommented `LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so`):

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src none;"
</IfModule>
```

I have stopped and started my Apache server however this code is not taking effect.
If I set the CSP inside of my .php file (eg in `header.php`) it works fine:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src none;">
```

Please note I have set it to `none` just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved the CSP outside of the `<VirtualHost *:80>` section and it's now working as expected. I actually moved it into `httpd-ssl.conf` and inside of the `<VirtualHost ---.com:443>` section and it's working as intended.